# I am unable to select option value from dropdown in using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to select the value from dropdown menu from this website https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/OPUS/, I did use this code to do that

```html
    #select antenna type
antenna_type="TRM57971.00     NONE"

    element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//span[@class="select2-selection select2-selection--single"]').click()
    target=driver.find_element(By.ID,"select2-ant_type-container")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", target)
    time.sleep(1)

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/*[@class='select2-results__option'][text()='%s']" %(antenna_type)).click()
```

but it is throwing me an error

```html
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/*[@class='select2-results__option'][text()='TRM57971.00     NONE']"}
```

I did try few other methods also but it throws me multiple errors. How to select the value of anteena, so i can proceed with the form and submit it. Thank you in advance.